# Catch bad signature error for an specific function call

Tags: python, error-handling

I could have a code like this:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

# User chooses function and parameters
function = sum
params = {"a": 5, "b": 3}

try:
    ret = sum(**params)
    print(ret)
except TypeError:
    # Function called with bad signature
    print("Wrong parameters for the chosen function!")
except:
    print("Internal error")
```

The user of the module would choose a function and a dictionary of params. The function is run and the user gets told if the parameters of sum are wrong (because calling a function with incorrect parameters would raise a `TypeError`). If the function is bugged and raises other type of exception, 'internal error' is shown.

**Well, almost.** The `sum` function could be bugged and raise `TypeError` because of a bad call made inside the function. That should be reported as an internal error.

How can I catch the case where the `sum` function is called with wrong parameters and avoid false positives when a `TypeError` is raised within the function?

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in the general case. Consider someone using `functools.partial` or a decorator, for example.

Comment: I've always thought python should raise something more descriptive than TypeError when you have the wrong number of arguments/wrong signature.  But unfortunately the only way to distinguish this TypeError from another is to actually look at the message.

Comment: You can catch `TypeError`s in the inside function, making sure that "false positives" are omitted.

Comment: @Veedrac An RPC-like service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP-0362](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) defines a signature object which can be helpful. It's included by default in Python 3.3+ but [there is a backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs) for earlier versions.

This would be the code using the signature object to check for correct parameters:

```
import sys
try:
    from inspect import signature
except ImportError:
    from funcsigs import signature

def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

# User chooses function and parameters
function = sum
params = {"a": 5, "b": 3}

try:
    # Check signature
    signature(function).bind(**params)
except TypeError:
    # Function called with bad signature
    print("Wrong parameters for function!")
    sys.exit(1)

# Signature is fine, continue...
try:
    ret = sum(**params)
    print(ret)
except:
    # Exception in function
    print("Internal error")
```

Comment: `except` is better as `except Exception` unless you want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` too, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have four options, none of which are ideal

- Tailor all the functions manually.
- Use function introspection to check whether the arguments are valid for the function. This can miss edge-cases, like wrapped functions with generic decorators. See ntrrgc's answer for how to check this.
- Check the error message. This can catch internal errors, though, if the functions then incorrectly calls another.
- Live without.